# Generate pythagorean triples to infinity

Tags: prolog

I want to **generate all the pythagorean triples** (generate a new triplet every time the user asks for a new solution by using ; in prolog).

I have tried to modify the following code, which displays all the pythagorean triples up to a given N value (max limit).

Original algorithm to generate triples up to a given value N:

```
pythagora(X,Y,Z,N) :-
   length(_, N),
   between(1,N,X),
   between(1,N,Y),
   between(1,N,Z),
   Z*Z =:= X*X + Y*Y.
```

I've tried to eliminate the max limit number N and replace it with `inf` or `infinite` but obviously the program dies. What other predicate can I use, except `between` to generate number for testing?

My attempt was the following:

```
pythagora(X,Y,Z):- between(1,inf,X), between(1,inf,Y), between(1,inf,Z), Z*Z =:= X*X + Y*Y.
```

**I am completely new to Prolog so I apologize if the question seems noobish. I hope you can show me the proper way to achieve my goal. Thank you.**

Comment: Why do you use `length(_, N)` here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not using length. That was in the original algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the approach you propose is that `X` and `Y` are set through the `between/3` calls, but then `Z` is set as well. Now regardless whether `Z*Z =:= X*X + Y*Y` or not, we will only increment *`Z`*, and this until infinity. So after a certain value for `Z`, will never generate a Pythagorean triplet anymore, but `between/3` will keep proposing new values for `Z`.

We can solve the problem by first setting `Z` (which is here always the largest value of the triplet). Then we know that `X` and `Y` will always be between `1` and `Z` (well the bounds can be set more "tight", but I leave this as an exercise), so we can implement this as:

```
pythagora(X,Y,Z) :-
    between(1, inf, Z),
    between(1, Z, X),
    between(1, Z, Y),
    Z*Z =:= X*X + Y*Y.
```

since `X` and `Y` are unified by a `between/3` call, with a *limited* number of values, we know for sure that eventually these calls will end, and we will thus try to find triplets for a *higher* value for `Z`.

With this approach we get:

```
?- pythagora(X, Y, Z).
X = 3,
Y = 4,
Z = 5 ;
X = 4,
Y = 3,
Z = 5 ;
X = 6,
Y = 8,
Z = 10 ;
X = 8,
Y = 6,
Z = 10 ;
X = 5,
Y = 12,
Z = 13 ;
X = 12,
Y = 5,
Z = 13 ;
X = 9,
Y = 12,
Z = 15
```

There is some duplication here, so we can decide to add an extra limitation that `X` is always less than `Y`:

```
pythagora(X,Y,Z) :-
    between(1, inf, Z),
    between(1, Z, X),
    between(X, Z, Y),
    Z*Z =:= X*X + Y*Y.
```

then we get:

```
?- pythagora(X, Y, Z).
X = 3,
Y = 4,
Z = 5 ;
X = 6,
Y = 8,
Z = 10 ;
X = 5,
Y = 12,
Z = 13 ;
X = 9,
Y = 12,
Z = 15 ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me. Cheers :)